# Saving log files from linux server

Tags: linux, shell, logging, linux-kernel, archive

im trying to archive the log files which i want to show now. But i cant find the problem, why it isn't working. Need help!

```
#!/bin/bash

logs="/appl/test/logs"
gzfiles="/appl/test/logs/*.gz"
scripts="/appl/test/scripts"
logsarchive="/appl/test/logs_archive"

find $logs -type f -mtime 0 ! -regex "*.gz" ! -exec /sbin/fuser -s "{}" 2>/dev/null \; -exec gzip {} \; &> $scripts/logcleaner.log
find $logsarchive -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm {} 2>/dev/null \; &>> $scripts/logcleaner.log
mv $gzfiles $logsarchive 2>/dev/null &>> $scripts/logcleaner.log
```

/appl/test/logs ucs_access_p.log* - These logs are didn't get saved. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You can debug this by just running find command with conditions, but everything after -exec removed. If it doesn't show any files, play with conditions. Remove them one by one and see what happens.

Comment: Some versions of find require parentheses to properly group conditions. Also, you may try changing -mtime 0 to -mtime +1 or -1 and check.